# How to react to specific BroadcastReceiver intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to do basic receiver and let it display a toast whenever battery status changes, but when one changes, all other toasts are also executed.

I am manipulating the battery using AVD through telnet

```
public class battery1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String strCharge = null, strHealth = null, strPlug = null;
        int status, health, plugged, temp;

        status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (intent.hasExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS)) {
            switch(status) {
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
                strCharge = "Charging";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:
                strCharge = "Discharging";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
                strCharge = "Full";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN:
                strCharge = "Unknown";
                break;
            }

            Toast.makeText(context,"Charging status: " + strCharge, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1);
        if (intent.hasExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH))
        {
            switch (health) {
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD:
                strHealth = "Dead";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD:
                strHealth = "Good";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE:
                strHealth = "Over voltage";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT:
                strHealth = "Overheat";
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN:
                strHealth = "Unknown";
                break;
            }

            Toast.makeText(context,"Battery health is " + strHealth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: all means two Toast or more than two ?

Comment: More than two, all of them get displayed one after another. I only want the toast to show only when something changes e.g battery health changed from good to dead and etc

Comment: @Doshag: Can you please me, how you are manipulating the battery using telnet?

Comment: While your AVD is running under eclipse, use CMD to connect to that instance by typing:
    telnet localhost 5554
Where 5554 is the AVD instance/session number (I believe), then:
    power help

To get a list of the possible commands, for example:

    power status dead
    power status good

Etc..

Comment: @Doshag: Thanks. Got it from http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/07/changing-the-battery-percentage-in-an-avd-android-virtual-device-emulator/

Comment: @Doshag: It is working fine. I am getting only two receivers, one for the charging state and another for the health. Are you registering multiple receivers?